# Synchronize between two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, synchronization

i have two arrays in php, one is a list of files and the other has uniqueid() => ("file", uid, meetings)

array 1:

```
$madeFromFilesArray = array(
    "index",
    "contact",
    "reportA",
    "reportB",
);
```

array 2:

```
$LoadedArray = array(
    5156e1b122c2b => array("index", uid, meetings),
    5156e1b122c2c => array("about", uid, meetings),
    5156e1b122c2d => array("contact", uid, meetings),
    5156e1b122c2e => array("reportB", uid, meetings),
);
```

array 1 is the updated one.
i need to sync array 2 with 1. for example delete "about" from array 2 because it is not in 1 and add reportA to array 2 because it is in 1 and not in 2.
so the final array is:

result array3:

```
$LoadedArray = array(
    5156e1b122c2b => array("index", uid, meetings),
    5156e1b122c2d => array("contact", uid, meetings),
    5156e1b122c2e => array("reportB", uid, meetings),
    5156e1b122c2f => array("reportA", uid, meetings),
);
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Is anything in particular *unclear* to you?

Comment: please post code in php because as it is, I see multiple answers depending on your structure

Comment: I know it's pseudo code, but array 2 can't possibly look like that. Take a look at the outcome http://3v4l.org/dVuiZ see the problem? only one value remains because the key is overwritten. var_dump or print_r your actual array and show us how it really looks, it's impossible to help with what you've given us so far.

Comment: serial num is serial num.. represents #### a number.. but fixed it so be more understood.

Comment: Ok, so how are we meant to determine what reportA's serialnum is or where its uid and meetings values come from?

Comment: i use uniqid() to set new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution, but I have no idea where `uid` and `meetings` come from or what they represent, so I used strings

```
$madeFromFilesArray = array(
    "index",
    "contact",
    "reportA",
    "reportB",
);

$LoadedArray = array(
    '5156e1b122c2b' => array("index", 'uid', 'meetings'),
    '5156e1b122c2c' => array("about", 'uid', 'meetings'),
    '5156e1b122c2d' => array("contact", 'uid', 'meetings'),
    '5156e1b122c2e' => array("reportB", 'uid', 'meetings'),
);

$seenFiles = array();
foreach ($LoadedArray as $key => $values) {
    if (!in_array($values[0], $madeFromFilesArray)) {
        unset($LoadedArray[$key]);
    } else {
        $seenFiles[] = $values[0];
    }
}

$missingFiles = array_diff($madeFromFilesArray, $seenFiles);
foreach ($missingFiles as $value) {
    $LoadedArray[uniqid()] = array($value, 'uid', 'meetings');
}
```

Comment: thank you very much :), i just hope if theres 1000 files it wont take forever to sync... marked as answare.